# Geo-autocomplete in Visual Basic 6?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vb6, maps

I want to implement a textbox in VB6 with geo-autocomplete. Is it possible? Someone have done it before? I was thinking in using a WebBrowse Control + Javascript, but I'm not really sure if thats gonna work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The textboxes can support auto complete of you have an appropriate data source. Can you elaborate on what geo-autocomplete is and what you want it to do? Once we know that, we may be able suggest a way to do it in VB6.

Comment: He might be looking for AutoSuggest which is somewhat different than AutoComplete. I'm not sure you can do that in VB6.

Comment: Thanks for your replys. What I want is a textbox that autocompletes addresses, just like [Places Autocomplete](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete). Just the textbox, no radio buttons, no maps.

Comment: Related question, but not exact duplicate: [combo box autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713398/how-can-i-create-an-autocomplete-combobox-in-vb6) rather than textbox.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but I've already figured out a solution that connects VB6 with GoogleMaps through Javascript. I'll be posting my solution soon.